# control reaching end of non-void function

Tags: c

```
bool binary(int value,int values[],int start,int end)
{

    //Binary search
    if(start>end)
        return false;

    int mid=(start+end)/2;

    if(value==values[mid])
            return true;
    else
    {
        if(value>values[mid])
            binary(value,values,mid+1,end);

        else
            binary(value,values,start,mid-1);
    }
}
```

I'm getting the same error again and again.Tried a lot of changes

Comment: you're missing `return` in front of your recursion steps.

Comment: You didn't ask a question.

Comment: `binary(value,values,...);` should be `return binary(value,values,...);`

Comment: That worked at last .Thank you guys for the correction!

Answer (score 1):

You get this error because function `binary` is defined to return a `bool` value, but not all control paths actually contain a `return`-statement (note that once your `else`-path has been entered, the code will not reach even any return statement). Without interpreting your code to much, the most likely thing to fix this is the following:

```
bool binary(int value,int values[],int start,int end)
{
    //Binary search
    if(start>end)
        return false;

    int mid=(start+end)/2;

    if(value==values[mid])
            return true;
    else
    {
        if(value>values[mid])
            return binary(value,values,mid+1,end);

        else
            return binary(value,values,start,mid-1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The compiler deduces that when the `if` condition fails there's no return statement.

So, put return statement end of `binary()` function. like :

```
bool binary(int value,int values[],int start,int end)
{
        //Binary search 
        if(start>end)
                return false;

        int mid=(start+end)/2;

        if(value==values[mid])
                return true;
        else
        {
                if(value>values[mid])
                        return binary(value,values,mid+1,end);

                else
                        return binary(value,values,start,mid-1);
        }
}
```

Comment: Just beginning to learn some programming.Thanks for the help!